# How to update a MySQL row based on previous row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this:

**ACTUAL TABLE**

```
ID | Type  |   Number
----------+----------
1  |   x   |   2000
2  |   y   |   4500
3  |   y   |   4500
4  |   x   |   3000
5  |   y   |   5000
6  |   x   |   4000
7  |   y   |   7500
8  |   y   |   7500
```

And I want to update the `y` to be exact as the `x` before it:

**EXPECTED TABLE**

```
ID | Type  |   Number
----------+----------
1  |   x   |   2000
2  |   y   |   2000
3  |   y   |   2000
4  |   x   |   3000
5  |   y   |   3000
6  |   x   |   4000
7  |   y   |   4000
8  |   y   |   4000
```

How should I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Considering we may not know an exact OrderBy clause you're using and DB rows are really in random. You may have just to iterate over resultset and update once type=y value is found. Remember previous row values accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to incorporate it. Just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update based on your ID: 
`UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname> = (SELECT <fieldname> FROM <tablename> WHERE id = 1) WHERE id = 2`
It might work.

Comment: I got an error like this: Database query failed. You can't specify target table '<tablename>' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Well, the error above I got because I use INNER JOIN. I tried to use select statement for the INNER JOIN and it works. Thank you very much guys for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

`t` is tablename

`a` is type

`va` is number

```
update t join (
      select curr.id, max(prior.id) prior_id
        from t curr
        join t prior
          on prior.a = 'x'
             and prior.id < curr.id
       where curr.a = 'y'
    group by curr.id) g
          on g.id = t.id
        join t v on v.id = g.prior_id
   set t.va = v.va;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0126/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id, va into @max_id, @value_x FROM t 
WHERE a = 'x'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;


UPDATE t
set va = @value_x
where ID > @max_id;

COMMIT;
```

Try to get the value of x and id from the table first, into sql variables.
Then do a simple update using those variabes.

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN
     ( 

       SELECT y.*
            , MAX(x.number) max_number 
         FROM my_table y 
         JOIN my_table x
           ON x.type = 'x' 
          AND x.id <= y.id 
        GROUP 
           BY y.id

     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   SET a.number = b.max_number;
```